# Error Checking a project in Java

Tags: java, error-checking

My goal in the below code is to check for input that is longer than two places after the decimal point, then throw an exception. I cant seem to get it correct though. I am trying to use indexOf to get to the decimal point and then I want to check the length of the portion after it. If it is greater than 2 I want it to throw the exception.  Anybody have some tips for this situation?

```
 public ChangeJar(final String amount) {
    int i = amount.indexOf('.');
    String temp = amount.substring(i + 2);

    if(temp.length() > 2 ){
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("Too many decimal places!");
    }

    if (amount == null || Double.parseDouble(amount) < 0) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("amount cannot be null!");
    }
    double amt;
    try {
        amt = Double.parseDouble(amount);
    } catch (NumberFormatException ex) {
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Invalid entry. Format is 0.00.");
    }
    amountHelper(amt);
}
```

I also wanted to know how I could add error checking to this constructor as I dont want null inputs. I get an error when trying to add error checking that says the constructor call must be the first statement in the method.My code for the constructor is:

```
public ChangeJar(final ChangeJar other){
    if(other == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values cannot be null!");
    }
    this(other.quarters, other.dimes, other.nickels, other.pennies);
}



All suggestions are appreciated!
```

Answer (score 0):

As Java does not allow to put any statements before the super or constructor calls in a constructor. Hence you cant do this:

```
public ChangeJar(final ChangeJar other){
    if(other == null){
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Values cannot be null!");
    }
    this(other.quarters, other.dimes, other.nickels, other.pennies);
}
```

You may add the check in the constructor that you are calling.

Comment: You can also use a Factory Class or static Factory Methods and make your constructor protected. That lets you validate the parameters before instantiating the objects.

Comment: I am not sure how to add the checking to the called constructor because its parameters are integers.